# Concurrency is achieved in Go when setting to single core with blocking operations

Tags: go, concurrency, parallel-processing

I was testing how a blocking operation works on Go, and how it deprives other go-routines from having processor share, so I did that test:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
    "time"
)

func test2() {
    for i := 1; ; i++ {
        fmt.Println(i, time.Now())
    }
}

func test() {
    a := 100
    for i := 1; i < 1000; i++ {
        a = i*100/i + a
        fmt.Println("value: " , a )
    }
}

func main() {
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(1)
    go test2()
    for {
        test()
    }
}
```

As you can see in the example, first line of `main()` I'm setting Go to use a single core and a never ending task runs on, so that it blocks any other process, though I see results I didn't expect, I found out that both test and `test2` are running, each having it's time share (a larger time share per process that's longer than if I set the `GOMAXPROCS` to higher values). This is the output:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b3634be74d30fd36f552

How can I explain this?

P.S. I'm using `Go version 1.5.3`

**Update**

I made a little change by setting `GOMAXPROCS` to 2, removed `fmt.Println("value: " , a )` from test function, now, the program runs `test2` for some time and, the `test` function takes over and nothing else run!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An important distinction is that `GOMAXPROCS=1` doesn't limit the runtime to 1 core, it limits the number of OS threads actively running user code to 1. All (gc derived) Go programs are multithreaded.

In most cases a busy loop will interfere with the scheduler and/or garbage collection, sometimes even if `GOMAXPROCS > 1`. In your example though, the calls to the `test()` and `fmt.Println` functions are scheduling points, and those allow the runtime scheduler to execute other goroutines.

---

As you pointed out, if the call to `fmt.Println` is removed from `test`, the progress on `test2()` eventually stops (apparently the call to `test()` alone isn't sufficient to let the scheduler proceed. Maybe it's to fast, inlined, blocked by the internal for loop, so on).

In this case it is because the busy-loop calls to `test()` are preventing the GC from doing it's stop-the-world phase of garbage collection, and blocking the scheduler. You can verify this by running the program with `GOGC=off`.

The details of scheduling, cpu-bound tasks, garbage collection, etc. can change from release to release, but since goroutines are cooperatively scheduled, a busy-loop is always a mistake. If you have an actual need for a long running, cpu-bound loop, you can cooperate with the scheduler by ocasionally inserting a call to [`runtime.Gosched()`](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#Gosched) to yield to other goroutines.

Comment: @securecurve The go scheduler is partially preemptive. That means it does not interrupt running goroutines expect at points where the goroutine calls a) a function  b) `runtime.Gosched()`

Comment: @securecurve: added some more info. A busy loop is always a mistake, so contrived examples like this can always find ways to subvert the expected behavior of the runtime.